# Foundation.MonoTouchException while calling Azure cognitive services from an iOS app created with Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-cognitive-services

I am calling the [cognitive services image analyzer feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?pivots=programming-language-csharp) using C# SDK. The C# script runs fine by itself. But when I call it from an iOS app build by [Xamarin in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios/hello-ios-quickstart?pivots=macos), I am facing `Foundation.MonoTouchException` when running.
I think the details below should help understand the problem better.

Here is the Main.storyboard.
[image]

This is what the Viewcontroller.cs looks like:

```
using System;
using UIKit;


namespace colors
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            string list_of_colors = "";

            getColor.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                // Convert the phone number with text to a number
                // using PhoneTranslator.cs
                list_of_colors = await ApiCall.AnalyzeImageUrl(
                    URLholder.Text);

                display.Text = list_of_colors;
            };
        }

       
        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

    }
}
```

And here is what apiCall.cs looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;

namespace colors
{
    public static class ApiCall
    {
        /*
         * AUTHENTICATE
         * Creates a Computer Vision client used by each example.
         */
        public static ComputerVisionClient Authenticate(string endpoint, string key)
        {
            ComputerVisionClient client =
              new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key))
              { Endpoint = endpoint };
            return client;
        }
        public static async Task<string> AnalyzeImageUrl(string raw)
        {
            // Add your Computer Vision subscription key and endpoint to your environment variables. 
            // Close/reopen your project for them to take effect.
            string subscriptionKey = "COMPUTER_VISION_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY";
            string endpoint = "COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT";
            // Create a client
            ComputerVisionClient client = Authenticate(endpoint, subscriptionKey);
            IList<VisualFeatureTypes> features = new List<VisualFeatureTypes>()
            {
                VisualFeatureTypes.Color
            };
            Console.WriteLine($"Analyzing the image {Path.GetFileName(raw)}...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            // Analyze the URL image 
            ImageAnalysis results = await client.AnalyzeImageAsync(raw, features);

            return string.Join(",", results.Color.DominantColors);
        }
    }
}
```

This post is the closest to the solution I could find, but did not help. I am not wed to this method of accessing azure cognitive services. I am open to other approaches to access azure cognitive services in an iOS app if they are available. But this is preferred.

It's my first time trying to work with an iOS app and C#, go easy on me.

Edit: Here is the stack-trace.

```
eason: -[ViewController GetColor_TouchUpInside:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc1d0d10540
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3de6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff512539b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e5eb94 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49354af0 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 302
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e4286c ___forwarding___ + 1436
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e44b58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49326c1d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48cd5baa -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 223
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48cd5ef2 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 396
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48cd4e63 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 497
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49362508 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1359
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4936428d -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4501
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4933e6d1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493c94ce __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 7628
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493cc692 __handleEventQueueInternal + 6584
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493c2f35 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 88
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1c91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1bbc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1394 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9bf8e __CFRunLoopRun + 974
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b8a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38c39bbe GSEventRunModal + 139
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49325968 UIApplicationMain + 1605
    23  ???                                 0x00000001112e5035 0x0 + 4583215157
    24  ???                                 0x00000001112e4d83 0x0 + 4583214467
    25  ???                                 0x00000001106f8943 0x0 + 4570712387
    26  colors                              0x000000010ab8b2b1 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1569
    27  colors                              0x000000010aca3e48 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 136
    28  colors                              0x000000010aca92c5 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 117
    29  colors                              0x000000010aaf718c mono_jit_exec + 364
    30  colors                              0x000000010ada2ccd xamarin_main + 2685
    31  colors                              0x
```

Stack trace, requested by @Jason

Comment: See following : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74001/solve-nsinvalidargumentexception

Comment: @jdweng Let me look into that

Comment: what line causes the exception?  Where is the stack trace?

Comment: @Jason Edited the question

Comment: Do you have a function called `GetColor_TouchUpInside`? Could you please share the code for it? Also, what tutorial are you following?

Comment: @Saamer It is in Viewcontroller.cs within ```ViewDidLoad()``` method

Comment: In your ViewController.cs wrap your API call in the touchupinside function in a try-catch block, like this: `try{list_of_colors = await ApiCall.AnalyzeImageUrl(URLholder.Text);} catch(Exception ex){list_of_colors=ex.Message;}`